# getting exception while putting list data into the map

Tags: java

I am iterating over a list and and putting it contents over the map but the problen is that when I am returning that map I am geeting an exception could you please advise what is the reason behind it ..I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 100, Size: 100  as my list size is 100

```
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : result.entrySet()) {
    pairList.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}

int sum = 0;
int min = -1;
int max = -1;

int i = 0;
Pair p = pairList.get(i);

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
//Iterator iterator = pairList.iterator();
Iterator iterator = pairList.listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(sum == 0){
        min = (int) p.key;
        max = (int) p.key;
    }
    sum += p.value;
    if(sum < BARRIER) {
        max = (int) p.key;
    } else {
        if(sum > BARRIER) {
            i--;
        } else {
            max = (int) p.key;
        }
        System.out.println(min+"_"+max);
        result1.put(min,max);

        sum = 0;
    }
    i++;
    p = pairList.get(i);
}

System.out.println("#########");

System.out.println(result1.size());
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result1.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

folks please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting? Could you show us a stacktrace? Can you help us out here?

Comment: If I had to *guess* (which I do, since you're making us), you're getting a `ConncurrentModificationException` which the Javadoc tells you is *exactly* what will happen if you modify the structure while iterating through it.

Comment: I am geeting an exception could you please advise what is the reason behind it ..I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 100, Size: 100 as my list size is 100

Comment: @Brian Can you please advise how to overcome from this.

Comment: Well, arrays are **zero indexed**, which means you are trying to access the 101ist element of a 100 element array.

Comment: i am using arraylist not array first, can you please advise how to overcome from this.

Comment: This exception is **not from putting list data into the map**. It's from *getting* data from `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Thanks please advise how to overcome from this now

Comment: Whats the point of the iterator in your code?

Comment: does not get it can you please advise does things can be achieved without iterator also..?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero indexed. e.g. a 100-element array will actually have valid index range of [0,99]. I'm assuming this happens on the line `p = pairList.get(i);`

You need to implement some logic to make sure that you're not overstepping the bounds. You're already using an iterator to iterate through `pairList`, which would protect you from this, but you're also mixing in the index `i`, which defeats the purpose of the iterator.

At the very least, include a check before you try to access an element. Something like:

```
if (i >= pairList.size())
    break;
```

Comment: I have done it in this way please advise is it correct .. while (iterator.hasNext())  { if (i >= pairList.size()) break;  if(sum == 0){     min = (int) p.key;
  max = (int) p.key;    }

Comment: That doesn't look like relevant code. I think you need to read up on some basics like looping constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
p = pairList.get(i);
```

If your list size is 100, then allowed indexes are between 0 - 99.

Comment: ..Perfect thanks a lot now how could I over come from it shall i put an condition can you please advise that will help to grasp Thanks a lot