# getting indexs out of bound exception

Tags: java

I am getting an exception  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException , could you please advise what is the reason behind it ..I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 100, Size: 100  as my list size is 100

```
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : result.entrySet()){
    pairList.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}

int sum = 0;
int min = -1;
int max = -1;        

int i = 0;
Pair p = pairList.get(i);

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
//Iterator iterator = pairList.iterator();
Iterator iterator = pairList.listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(sum == 0) {
        min = (int) p.key;
        max = (int) p.key;
    }
    sum += p.value;
    if(sum < BARRIER){
        max = (int) p.key;
    } else {
        if(sum > BARRIER){
            i--;
        } else {
            max = (int) p.key;
        }
        System.out.println(min+"_"+max);
        result1.put(min,max);

        sum = 0;

    }
    i++;
    p = pairList.get(i);
}

System.out.println("#########");

System.out.println(result1.size());
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result1.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Now I am getting exception at the point `p = pairList.get(i);`Arrays are zero indexed. e.g. a 100-element array will actually have valid index range of [0,99]. I'm assuming this happens on the line p = pairList.get(i); 
now please advise how to overcome from this

Comment: What was wrong with your [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508097/getting-exception-while-putting-list-data-into-the-map)?

Comment: Asking the same question more than once is not a good way to get attention. If you are not getting good answers in your first question, consider editing it and adding some more information.

Comment: Add some comments in your program so that we can understand

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iterator to get the next list item instead of using pairList.get(i).
use

```
p =iterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the combination

```
    while (iterator.hasNext())    
    {

        ...
        i--
        ....
        i++;
        p = pairList.get(i);
```

Please read how to use `Iterator`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

it is a combination of `hasNext` and `next`. Alternatively, use "foreach" statement.

```
for (Pair p : pairList) {
```

.
If you need to iterate the access the list randomly using index (`i++` or `i--`) you need to protect your code with

```
if (i>=0 && i<pairList.size()) p = pairList.get(i);
else break; //??exit??
```

please note the method `hasNext` return true if you do not iterate over the iterator with the `next` method

```
p = pairList.next();
```

Finally, in your code

```
while(pairList.hasNext())
```

is equivalent to

```
while(true)
```

you ned a "`break`"